# Customized property is not enumerable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, types, properties, customization, enumerable

I defined my own "Age" type，as part of "Person" type, like this:

```
var Age=function(){
    year='1930',
    month='Jan'
}
var Person=function(){
    name='abc',
    age=new Age()
}
var o1=new Person()
console.log(o1.propertyIsEnumerable('age'))
```

My expectation is, as long as o1's age property is created from "Age", while its "year/month" can both be visited using string as index, then o1 is of enumerable type.
But the fact it, it prints "false".

Why is that, is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Please re-read the part of the JS tutorial where it talks about constructors and how to set instance properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining global variables not properties

```
var Age=function(){
    year='1930',
    month='Jan'
}
var Person=function(){
    name='abc',
    age=new Age()
}
```

Should be

```
var Age=function(){
    this.year='1930';
    this.month='Jan';
}
var Person=function(){
    this.name='abc';
    this.age=new Age();
}
```